# how to build image service website with sails.js

Tags: image, assets, sails.js

I am using sails.js  to build an image service website. There are lots of images need be shown on the webpage. And the website will allow users to  upload images as well. If I put it all images under assets folder, they will be copied  to .tmp/public everytime when i restart the sails server . it will be very slow.  Does anyone have an idea where should i put .Should I write a route rule to handle this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/assets are for your static contents (like css, frontendjs, ...).

If you have a lots of images you should place them in one folder of your server and write a route for showing it.

Or better: Use some Cloud-Hosting like amazonS3 or imageShack.

---

Example for middleware:

1.) create a file "express.js" in config/

2.) Put this code into the file and change to the right path (routing + your local folder):

```
module.exports.express = {
   customMiddleware: function(app){
     app.use('/images', require('../node_modules/sails/node_modules/express').static('/User/yourfolder'));
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I will try the first idea. could you give me a simple route example,please?